# Is struct A { int a[2] = {1, 2}; }; legal as per C++11?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-errors, standards

The following code is accepted by clang 3.4

```
struct A
{
    int a[2] = {1, 2};
};
```

However, vc++ 2014 CTP rejects it with an error message:

`error C2536: 'A::A::a': cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays`

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Clang, as usual, is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, It is legal but VC++ does not support this feature. It is the [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) of an [in-class member initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init).

Of course [the `=` sign is optional](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519) and your code is the same as the following code:

```
struct A
{
    int a[2] {1, 2};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's allowed by (but new with) C++11. Specifically, in C++03, the syntax for a class member was (§9.2):

> *member-declarator:*
>
> > *declarator pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>
> >
> >             declarator constant-initializer<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> *constant-initializer:*
>
> > *= constant-expression*

The only in-place initializers this allows are constant expressions. In C++11, however, the syntax has changed (still §9.2):

> *member-declarator:*
>
> > *declarator virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>*
> >     declarator brace-or-equal-initializer<sub>opt</sub>

This allows a "brace or equal initializer" in general, rather than being restricted to constant expressions as was required in C++03.

[Note that I've omitted a few irrelevant parts of the grammar here, such as the specification for bit-fields].